# Python logging format: Add a colon right after `levelname` and then pad it

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to achieve the following format:

```
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
```

My logger code currently looks like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(levelname)-9s %(message)s [%(name)s]",
)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

My logged messages look like this:

```
INFO     Application shutdown complete.
```

How can I add a colon right after the `levelname` before the padding?

Comment: You should be able to include the colon in the format string if I'm not mistaken. `%(levelname):-9s %(message)s [%(name)s]"` (sorry I can't test it at the moment)

Comment: I tried that and I get an error saying `ValueError: unsupported format character ':' (0x3a) at index 12`.

Comment: Ah darn, I knew it couldn't be that easy

Comment: Yeah, I wasted quite a lot of time on this. I know it's possible to do it by implementing a custom formatter, but I'd prefer this `basicConfig(): format` parameter approach. I wonder if there's a way to append plain string within `%()`

Comment: Format strings can be picky because it's expecting the logged info to follow the format you've given. I wonder if you could do `(levelname + ':')`...I suspect it'll complain about that as well though

Comment: I also tried that. This is the error: `ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: "levelname + ':'"`.

Comment: `%(levelname)4s: %(message)s [%(name)s]` should do it